# R confusion about slots and data classes

Tags: r

I did some pre-processing using some packages with specific data classes and now I am confused trying to access some of the data as I normally would.

```
    str(metadata)
'data.frame':   51 obs. of  11 variables:
Formal class 'sample_data' [package "phyloseq"] with 4 slots
  ..@ .Data    :List of 11
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 51 levels "1_S51","10_S60",..: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 ...
  .. ..$ : int  10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1 ...
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 13 levels "1","10","11",..: 2 3 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 ...
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 2 levels "Control","Stool": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 3 levels "Control","ZT14",..: 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 ...
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","Control": 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 3 levels "AdLib","Control",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 3 levels "Control","RC",..: 2 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 3 2 ...
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 3 levels "Control","Female",..: 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 ...
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "Control","RC_AdLib",..: 3 5 3 3 5 5 3 3 5 3 ...
  .. ..$ : Factor w/ 5 levels "Control","RC_1",..: 2 4 3 3 5 5 3 3 5 2 ...
  ..@ names    : chr  "SampleID" "SampleNumber" "MouseTime" "SampleType" ...
  ..@ row.names: chr  "10_S60" "11_S61" "13_S62" "14_S63" ...
  ..@ .S3Class : chr "data.frame"
```

For example before had my metadata as a "normal" data frame and could merge it with other data frames.  Now I am not sure how to do this.

```
dat.czm.annot.otu<-merge(dat.czm.otu,metadata,by.x="row.names",by.y="SampleID")

Error in validObject(.Object) :
```

invalid class “sample_data” object: Sample Data must have non-zero dimensions.

I have tried this workaround, but I was wondering if there is a different way that I am 'supposed' to be doing this.  Thanks

```
    metadata.2<-as.data.frame(slot(metadata,".Data"))
colnames(metadata.2)<-colnames(metadata)
```

Comment: Which package did you use? You can also access the slots using `@` like you'd use `$` (e.g.: `object@data`) in case this helps.

Comment: They're called S4 classes in R, check this reference: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html